# How to do force directed edge bundling in gephi?

Tags: gephi

Is is possible to do force directed edge bundling in gephi? I see a GSOC project completed in 2013 but I want to know if it is packaged with the standard release now. If yes, how to use it? 
Thanks a lot for the help

Answer (score 3):

It's possible in a demo build only. The project you refer to has been integrated [into this demo build](https://github.com/eduramiba/gephi/releases/tag/v0.8.1-fdeb-alpha) (a little over a year old, though). According to the developers, other things have to be addressed first before this makes it into the regular build. There is no estimated ship date.